# How can I populate a grid in a View based on some text boxes in the same View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

In my asp.net MVC site, i have a view with a empty grid and some textboxes, when the user fills those textboxes i need to get those values and make a new row for the grid.

How can i do that?

Thanks

ps(using Razor)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the online [GridView Filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/filtering) demo.

If the current "filter string" is empty (see the "Controller -> Filtering" action method; the "startsWith" parameter), do not initialize model.

If not empty, initialize the required model.